# Objective-c syntax confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax

Could anyone tell me the difference between

```
NSString* string;
```

And

```
NSString* string = [NSString string];
```

Comment: You mean where to put the `*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in C,

```
NSString *string;
```

declares the variable (pointer) `string` but gives it no value. This means you can't use the variable until you've initialized it, for example by doing `string = @"foo";`.

Note:

- If this is an instance variable it actually will be initialized automatically — to `nil`.
- If you use the variable somewhere in your code without initializing it in *every possible branch* (`if` conditions, etc.) then the compiler will complain. To avoid this you could just set it to an empty string or `nil` to start with.

---

The line

```
NSString *string = [NSString string];
```

uses the [`+string` method of the `NSString` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/string) to create an empty string. You could also use `@""`.

(Further note: I recommend using `NSString *string` instead of `NSString* string` because the former hides a syntax idiosyncrasy: `NSString *string1, *string2;` is the correct way to declare multiple pointer variables on one line.)

Answer (score 2):

### NSString *string;

The first your just declaring that there will be a variable that is an `NSString`, named `string`, but not initializing it.

You might do this when you want a string to contain one of a range of values, determined by some condition:

```
NSString *string;

if (condition) {
    string = @"This condition";
} else {
    string = @"That condition";
}
```

### NSString *string = [NSString string];

The second you are doing all of the above, with the additional step of initializing your `string` variable to an empty string.

You might do this when you want a string to contain a specific single value:

```
NSString *string = @"There are no conditions"
```

Comment: Oh right okay, so I could equally do NSString* string = @""; to match the 2nd example?

Comment: @Ben_hawk yes you can. Also @{} for `NSDictionary`, @[] for `NSArray` and @() to assign a `NSNumber` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string;
```

Creates a pointer but not a string object (instance). It may be initialized to nil or not depending on where it is an compiler options. In other words it creates a place (memory storage) for a pointer to an `NSString` bot no `NSString` object.

```
NSString *string = [NSString string];
```

Creates an empty string object (instance) and a pointer to it.